# html_nodes return an empty list for complex table

Tags: r, rvest

I would like to webscraping the table in the following website: https://www.timeshighereducation.com/world-university-rankings/2021/world-ranking#!/page/0/length/25/sort_by/rank/sort_order/asc/cols/stats
I am using the following code but it is not working, thank you in advance.

```
library(rvest)
library(xml2)
library(dplyr)
link <- "https://www.timeshighereducation.com/world-university-rankings/2021/world-ranking#!/page/0/length/25/sort_by/rank/sort_order/asc/cols/stats"
page<- read_html(link)


rank<- page %>% html_nodes(".sorting_2") %>% html_text()
university<-page %>% html_nodes(".ranking-institution-title ") %>% html_text() 
statistics<-page %>% html_nodes(".stats") %>% html_text()
```

Comment: What isn't working? I can see by disabling javascript the data is dynamically added so you will need RSelenium or examine the network tab to see where data is coming from (if by additional xhr from landing page)

Comment: Data is coming from here: https://www.timeshighereducation.com/sites/default/files/the_data_rankings/world_university_rankings_2021_0__fa224219a267a5b9c4287386a97c70ea.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Terms and Services](https://www.timeshighereducation.com/terms-and-conditions) of this site state: "Use data mining, robot, spider, scraping or similar automated data gathering, extraction or publication tools for any purpose."

That being said, you can read the json file that @QHarr found:

```
library(jsonlite)
url <- "https://www.timeshighereducation.com/sites/default/files/the_data_rankings/world_university_rankings_2021_0__fa224219a267a5b9c4287386a97c70ea.json"
x <- read_json(url, simplifyVector = TRUE)
head(x$data) # give you the data frame with universities
```

Now you have a well structured R list. The `$data` element contains a data frame with the stats of each university in rows. The other 3 list elements only provide supplementary information.